# Fixing ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in JAVA Spring / angular JS GET request

Tags: java

**Facing strange issue while making get request from angular.**

Spring Controller returns the data in JSON format (I've verified this in debugger@eclipse), but I am facing "**net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**" error on browser console i.e. at Angular side response is not received and error pops up on console.

Do I have to increase any buffer size parameters of server? Or how can I fix this issue???
Any inputs/leads will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did you fix this? I am getting the same error on angular. Please help. thanks. i get it for large number of records